# Regex Match word even it contains some char[dash,dot,..]

Tags: c#, regex

im trying to build a regex that find strings like

```
member.php?1078959-AmirAli
member.php?1078959-Amir-Ali
member.php?1078959-Amir-Al-i
member.php?1078959-Amir.Ali
member.php?1078959-Amir_Ali
member.php?1078959-Amir____Ali
```

i tried to make one :
Regex: `member.php\?\d{1,30}\-(\w+)`

But here is the problem , this regex cant support characters like [ - , . ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[ ]` brackets to match any of a set of characters. Also, you forgot to escape the `.` in `member.php`

```
member\.php\?\d{1,30}\-([\w\,\-\.]+)
```

Comment: No need to escape these characters in the brackets: `[-.,\w]` is perfectly find and more readable.